# html5 canvas with absolute position doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

Canvas with absolute position doesn't work as you can see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/733zs/1/ (Tested in Firefox and Chrome) The Rectangle should have a size of 500x500 pixel.

Is there a way to make it work, without setting width and height manually? Or do I have made any mistakes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must set width and height manually.

This can be done through JavaScript onresize event - which is fine because you almost always need to redraw your canvas surface onresize anyways.

EDIT:

From W3 spec, here is the canvas DOM interface:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html

```
interface HTMLCanvasElement : HTMLElement {
           attribute unsigned long width;
           attribute unsigned long height;

  DOMString toDataURL(in optional DOMString type, in any... args);
  void toBlob(in FileCallback, in optional DOMString type, in any... args);

  object getContext(in DOMString contextId, in any... args);
};
```

> The canvas element has two attributes to control the size of the
>   coordinate space: width and height. These attributes, when specified,
>   must have values that are valid non-negative integers. The rules for
>   parsing non-negative integers must be used to obtain their numeric
>   values. If an attribute is missing, or if parsing its value returns an
>   error, then the default value must be used instead. The width
>   attribute defaults to 300, and the height attribute defaults to 150.

Comment: so you mean for 'canvas' you have to do it manually but for 'div' not?

Comment: Correct canvas requires Height and Width. Can not be done via Right and Bottom.

Comment: so I tested this one: http://jsfiddle.net/733zs/4/ I have to set width, and height manually, but canvas has these values in offsetwidth and offsetheight

Comment: No, it's not a bug. Also, in my last comment I didn't mean "Correct canvas ...", I meant "Correct. Canvas ..."

Comment: +1 for `onresize` and I'd +1 again for linking to and quoting the spec.  Pass on the secret: specs can be worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

The rectangle is being clipped because the canvas element is only 300,150 pixels big.

http://jsfiddle.net/733zs/3/

Comment: I know, but why is it not as big as the page? My css says 0px to the left 0px to the right 0px to the top and 0 px to the bottom.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The positioning is working correctly.  You're just drawing the black box in the lower right corner of the canvas.

Comment: why not left and right at the same time? for div's it is working.